# Is there an application in Ubuntu to cast my android screen with sound?

Tags: software-recommendation, android, screen

Could there possibly be an application similar to '**Windows Connect**' (which runs seamlessly on Windows for me) for Linux with Audio and Video both casted to the Laptop?

I know `scrcpy` which can be used to mirror screen and `usbaudio` to route audio(which is not supported in Android 10).

Thanks.